# Spring MVC binding

Tags: binding, spring-mvc

I have the following command object:

```
public class User {
    private Department department;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String login;
    private String password;
...
}
```

which should be rendered at jsp page:

```
<form:input path="lastName" />
<form:input path="department.name"/>
<form:input path="department.description"/>
```

So when I submit with empty department.name and department.description the Spring auto-instantiate object Department with empty properties. (See https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6032 I would keep autoGrowNestedPaths=true)

What is need to do for getting back User object where Department object=null?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would do the trick but you can register a custom editor for both "department.name" and "department.description". In this custom editor in the setAsText() method only set the value when the string is not empty. So if you don't have more properties on this element the editors will prevent to call the setter on the object (what I'm not sure if the object won't be instantiated even when no property is populated on it, I think it won't but I'm not completely sure). The problem would be that if only one property is empty the empty attribute would be populated as null.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I register the editor like this: dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Department.class, new DepartmentEditor()); and by the way the User object comes with instantiated Department with empty atributes

Comment: Have you set breakpoints on setters for name and description (just to see that the editor is well registered and they are not invoked). Another way to go could be setting these inputs to disable before serializing the form with javascript, because disabled inputs won't be sent when sending the form.

Answer (score 5):

> What is need to do for getting back
>   User object where Department
>   object=null?

If you are looking for controller specific solution, then find all the empty nested params and set these params as disallowed fields.

```
@InitBinder(value="user")
    public void bind(WebDataBinder dataBinder, WebRequest webRequest) {
        List<String> emptyParams = new ArrayList<String>();
        Iterator<String> itr = webRequest.getParameterNames();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            String name = itr.next();
            if(name.startsWith("department.")) {
                Object value = webRequest.getParameter(name);
                if("".equals(value)) {
                    emptyParams.add(name);
                }
            }
        }
        if(!emptyParams.isEmpty()) {
            dataBinder.setDisallowedFields(emptyParams.toArray(new String[emptyParams.size()]));
        }
    }
```

If you are looking for a generic solution create a custom data binder and remove all nested params that are empty.

```
public class CustomDataBinder extends ServletRequestDataBinder {

    @Override
    protected void doBind(MutablePropertyValues mpvs) {
        PropertyValue[] pvArray = mpvs.getPropertyValues();
        for (PropertyValue pv : pvArray) {
            boolean nestedProperty = PropertyAccessorUtils.isNestedOrIndexedProperty(pv.getName());
            if(nestedProperty && "".equals(pv.getValue())) {
                mpvs.removePropertyValue(pv);
            }
        }
        super.doBind(mpvs);
    }

}
```

And to use CustomDataBinder you must have custom HandlerAdapter.

```
public class StandardAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter extends AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter    {
    @Override
    protected ServletRequestDataBinder createBinder(HttpServletRequest request, Object target, String objectName) throws Exception {
    CustomDataBinder dataBinder = new CustomDataBinder (target, objectName);
    return dataBinder;
   }
}
```